Mysql replication - Access denied for user 'repl'@'hostname' (using password: YES)
I had setup mysql replication using percona Xtrabackup. Replication was from my web server to my local machine. It used to work but my ISP changed IP address and replication stopped working. I'm getting this error:
mysql> SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
......
             Replica_IO_State: Connecting to source
....
....
Last_IO_Errno: 1045
Last_IO_Error: Error connecting to source 'repl@x.x.x.x:1234'. This was attempt 29/86400, with a delay of 60 seconds between attempts. Message: Access denied for user 'repl'@'hostname' (using password: YES)               

I can connect to source from replica via command line and access source's db via show database and use database commands
mysql --host=x.x.x.x --user=repl --password='pwd';

On Master
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000081 | 75494370 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

I'm not able to figure out what is wrong with replication? How to find out issue and fix it?
Update
Few more commands
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'hostname';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'repl'@'hostname';
+----------------------------------------------------------+
+--+ | Grants for repl@hostname                            |
+--+ | GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO `repl`@`hostname` |
+--+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
+----------------------------------------------------------+

Command
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO
    SOURCE_HOST='$sourceip',
    SOURCE_USER='repl',
    SOURCE_PASSWORD='$replicapass',
    SOURCE_LOG_FILE='Source-bin.000001',
    SOURCE_LOG_POS=481;


Have you configured your master via log_bin=/some/path/binlog? Try SHOW MASTER STATUS; on master host to verify if replication enabled.

@Kondybas I've updated my question. I think GRANT command doesn't do anything. How do we check & fix it?

SHOW GRANTS work for current user that is root@localhost You have to use SHOW GRANTS FOR 'repl'@'hostname' instead

@Kondybas thanks for pointing that. I've updated my question. Now, I've no clue what is going on? P.S. I don't have SSL specified for this connection, it worked in the past without SSL so not sure if this is an issue now, just wanted to mention.

@ErgestBasha I've updated my question with CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO command. I'm not sure why you need this? In my case Replica's IP is changed.

@ErgestBasha Yes, that is what my assumption was. I've added new user with new IP on source's mysql. I can also access source MySQL from replica via command line so access is not an issue. One problem is that source is taking replica's hostname instead of IP so I had to add replica's hostname as new user repl@hostname in the source. I'm not sure if this hostname thingy makes us do anything extra? Where do I run  GET_SOURCE_PUBLIC_KEY=1 on the CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO ? On source or on replica?

@ErgestBasha adding entry in /etc/hosts doesn't have any impact. I've added entry in /etc/hosts and rebooted server. It seems source can't resolve IP address that is why it is doing reverse look up to see the hostname instead of IP address. I think this is the actual problem. I'm not sure how to fix this.

It turned out that I was using wrong password in adding repl user on the source. The password used here should be the same password which was specified on CHANGE MASTER TO command.
